# DeviceInfo.getUniqueID is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The react-native project I'm working on already use *react-native-device-info*. When I tried to add `Android-${DeviceInfo.getUniqueID()}` to a header in a request, I get this error:

```
  { TypeError: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID is not a function
        at makeRequest (~/code/rn/src/services/api-client.js:46:39)
```

How can that be? I import it like this on the top of the files it is used in.

```
import * as DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
```

If I change the import statement to `import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';`, then I get this error:

`TypeError: _reactNativeDeviceInfo2.default.getUniqueID is not a function`

```
export function makeRequest(endpoint, method, token, csrfToken = null, body = null) {
    const config = {
        method,
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            Applikasjon: 'KONSERNAPP',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'X-App-Version': `Android-${DeviceInfo.getUniqueID()}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            token,
        },
        timeout: 120000,
    };
```

Comment: have you solved this issue in the meantime?

Comment: I can't really remember. I think I solved it in a hackish workaround.

Comment: If you encounter anything like that in version `3.0.0`, try to revert to `2.3.2`.

Comment: same problem when updated today, `yarn add react-native-device-info@2.3.2` to downgrade

Answer (score 8):

since react-native-device-info is upgraded to `4.x.x` its method typo is bit changed, it is now accepting `DeviceInfo.getUniqueId()` instead of `DeviceInfo.getUniqueID()`

Answer (score 3):

This solved it for me
`DeviceInfo.getUniqueId()`
instead of
`DeviceInfo.getUniqueID()`.
Lolz. It's a typo in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading:

-> yarn add react-native-device-info@2.3.2

then use  DeviceInfo.getUniqueID()

Working for me.